# Column Comparison Over Two Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

### Question

Is it possible to compare two columns of two different tables which are in different databases and servers?

If so I would like to then do an update where the columns match to update a column in one of the tables taking the information from the other.

### Sudo Code

```
update table1
set table1-column1 = table2-column1
where table1column2 = table2column2
```

**NB: Table1 and Table2 are on different servers for arguments sake (server1 and server2)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx) to the other server and then make use of it link any other table with the sever name in front of the database name and namespace. `OtherServer.Database.dbo.Table`